# Firebase's record structure best practice

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm developing a project with Firebase and I think it would be helpful to add the record's own key to itself, but I haven't found any reference on that.

Does anyone have any input on that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the [Structure your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) section of the Firebase documentation? It's a good reference for your question.

Comment: I did. As far as I understand, it tells you how to structure n-n relationships. Another question I have is how should we structure 1-n? Example: we have (courses 1-n lessons), do we add a `lessons` field to the `courses` and `courseId` to the lesson?